# Why doesn't my XSL find anything to process in this XML?

Tags: xslt, cognos

Why doesn't my XSL find anything to process in this XML? I am trying to convert cognos xml report output into another form (yes I know cognos produces html, but I need something else). It just produces the word "Caption:" and stops.

Here is my XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:template match="rows">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="rowEdge"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="rowEdge">
        <b>Caption:</b> <xsl:value-of select="caption"/><br/>
        <xsl:if test="@id">
            <b>id:</b> <xsl:value-of select="@id"/><br/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="rowEdge">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="rowEdge"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <html>
        <head><title>%s</title></head>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="dataset/crosstab/rows"/>
        </body>
    </html>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the XML (I had to delete some, but should give an idea):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
 <dataset xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <crosstab>
 <values>
  <value row="R1" col="C1" xs:nil="true" /> 
  <value row="R1" col="C2" xs:nil="true" /> 
  <value row="R1" col="C3" xs:nil="true" /> 
  <value row="R1" col="C4" xs:nil="true" /> 
  <value row="R1" col="C5" xs:nil="true" /> 
  <value row="R1" col="C6" xs:nil="true" /> 
  <value row="R1" col="C7" xs:nil="true" /> 
  <value row="R1" col="C8" xs:nil="true" /> 
  <value row="R1" col="C9" xs:nil="true" /> 
  <value row="R2" col="C1">0</value> 
  <value row="R2" col="C2">12.61728395</value> 
  <value row="R2" col="C3">1320.40677966</value> 
  <value row="R2" col="C4">7</value> 
  <value row="R2" col="C5">1.90318499</value> 
  <value row="R2" col="C6">108.66456135</value> 
  <value row="R2" col="C7">776.61407946</value> 
  <value row="R2" col="C8">-0.86007907</value> 
  <value row="R2" col="C9">46.53571429</value> 
</values>
 <corner>
  <caption>Time Period: DCG Incurred Paid Year</caption> 
  </corner>
 <columns>
 <colEdge>
  <caption>Jan 02 to Dec 02 {All Data} CRxIp</caption> 
 <colEdge>
  <caption>2002</caption> 
 <colEdge id="C1">
  <caption>Member Age Avg</caption> 
  </colEdge>
 <colEdge id="C2">
  <caption>Days Supply Per Script Rx</caption> 
  </colEdge>
 <colEdge id="C3">
  <caption>Net Pay Per Pat Med</caption> 
  </colEdge>
 <colEdge id="C4">
  <caption>Days LOS Admit Acute</caption> 
  </colEdge>
 <colEdge id="C5">
  <caption>Days LOS Admit Acute</caption> 
  </colEdge>
 <colEdge id="C6">
  <caption>Allow Amt PMPM Med and Rx {Cmpl}</caption> 
  </colEdge>
 <colEdge id="C7">
  <caption>Allow Amt PMPM Med and Rx {Cmpl}</caption> 
  </colEdge>
 <colEdge id="C8">
  <caption>% Diff Allow Amt PMPM Med and Rx {Cmpl}</caption> 
  </colEdge>
 <colEdge id="C9">
  <caption>Relative Risk Score Prosp Explan NonRescaled</caption> 
  </colEdge>
  </colEdge>
  </colEdge>
  </columns>
 <rows>
 <rowEdge>
  <caption>Subsets</caption> 
 <rowEdge>
  <caption>Plan Type Medstat</caption> 
 <rowEdge id="R1">
  <caption>Cohort Medstat</caption> 
  </rowEdge>
  </rowEdge>
  </rowEdge>
 <rowEdge>
  <caption>Chronic Episodes</caption> 
 <rowEdge>
  <caption>HMO (Managed Care)</caption> 
 <rowEdge id="R2">
  <caption>Females, Ages &lt; 1</caption> 
  </rowEdge>
</rowEdge>
 </rowEdge>
 </rows>
  </crosstab>
  </dataset>
```

Comment: It looks like your root template is a little messed up - should the html part a the bottom go to the first template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0 (which you are using), default namespaces are not taken into account in XPath expressions.

Whet you need to do is:

1) Assign a prefix to the default namespace of your instance document in your XSLT transformation, for instance:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="cog:http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

2) Use this prefix before each element name (but not before attribute names) in your XPath expressions:

```
<xsl:template match="cog:rowEdge">
    <b>Caption:</b> <xsl:value-of select="cog:caption"/><br/>
    <xsl:if test="@id">
       <b>id:</b> <xsl:value-of select="@id"/><br/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="cog:rowEdge">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="cog:rowEdge"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Note: you don't need to test that there is a `cog:rowEdge` before applying the templates: the apply-templates won't do anything if there are no nodes in its select attribute anyway ;) ...

There are a couple of other errors in the stylesheet:

1. Templates can't be embedded
2. There must be a version attribute in the `xsl:stylesheet` element.

The correct stylesheet would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:cog="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <html>
            <head>
                <title>%s</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="cog:dataset/cog:crosstab/cog:rows"/>
            </body>
        </html>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cog:rows">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="cog:rowEdge"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cog:rowEdge">
        <b>Caption:</b>
        <xsl:value-of select="cog:caption"/>
        <br/>
        <xsl:if test="@id">
            <b>id:</b>
            <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
            <br/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="cog:rowEdge"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks. I also had to invoke it this way: <xsl:apply-templates select="cog:dataset/cog:crosstab/cog:rows"/>

Comment: The recursion is not working, it just prints out the entire text (parent + children) of that first rowEdge and quits.

Comment: Well, I had focused on the namespace issue with is a very common one, but looking at your XSLT, I see that there is another issue: you can't embed templates within templates as you're doing! To fix it you need to move the embedded templates out of the one for the root node (/) and to add the prefix before all the element names in all the XPath expressions.